# variables in play views

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I've found a few answers online to my issue but all for older versions of play which no longer work.

I am trying to find a way to use a variable as part of the template path.
I understand that this will remove the type checking etc, but its for a generator/prototyping/internal tool and isn't something that will see the public/outside world.

here's the codez:

The best answer I can find as a work around is:

```
def index(page: String) = Action {
   page match {
      case "something" => Ok(views.html.examples.something())
      case "else" => Ok(views.html.examples.else())
      case "another" => Ok(views.html.examples.elements.another())
   }
}
```

ideally something like this would make more sense:

```
def index(page: String) = Action {
  Ok(views.html.getClassFromStringOrSomething(page));
}
```

I am using the latest play framework (2.5.*) with scala.

is using a match the only way? 
There must be a dynamic why to return a view?

n.b. I have found loads of suggestions online which use `play.api.templates.Html/play.twirl.api.Html` which seem to no longer work, `Html` can't be found so im guessing the api has changes other the versions.

Using that I get:

```
def index(page: String, parent: String) = Action {

  val clazz: Class[_] = Play.current.classloader.loadClass(page)
  val render: Method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("render")
  val view = Some(render.invoke(clazz).asInstanceOf[play.twirl.api.Html])
  Ok(view)
}
```

This give me the error 
`Cannot write an instance of Some[play.twirl.api.Html] to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[Some[play.twirl.api.Html]]` and this is where I'm stuck

Comment: FYI: `play.api.templates.Html` changed to `play.twirl.api.Html` (Twirl is the name of the templating engine which was spun off from Play.)

Comment: How do you expect to provide arguments to these dynamic views? You're probably best using a completely different templating engine like [Jtwig](http://jtwig.org/). Play is not tied to Twirl - it's just the default.

Comment: the arguments would be a dynamic portion of the url. imagine I have 1000 pre made twirl views, all named as per there url. I dont want to add a controller / match case for each one.

Comment: The routes aspect is pretty simple to do. I did try replacing templates.Html with the twirl one but just hit a bus load of errors. I'll post the code up

Comment: You're wrapping the `Html` value (`view`) in `Some(...)` for no reason. Remove that and it should "work" (assuming the template has no arguments, and with a whole load of other caveats!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added an answer here solely to help anyone else hitting this issue.

@Mikesname was correct, remove the `Some()` and it 'should' all work fine.

The issue was that I was dynamically loading the class/view name, but I wasn't using the full class name. I was loading `something` when I should have been loading `view.html.something`.

Heres the code I used to get the feature working
(needs cleaning up but it's working, also accounts for views named `index` inside a directory, i.e. `views.html.parent -> /parent/index.scala.html`

```
    package controllers

import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}

import play.api.Play
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}

import play.twirl.api.Html

@Singleton
class PathController @Inject() extends Controller {

  def index(page: String, parent: String, grandparent: String) = Action {
     Ok(buildView(buildClassName(page, parent, grandparent)))
  }

  def buildClassName(page: String, parent: String, grandparent: String): String = {
    val pathGrandParent = if (grandparent != null) grandparent  + '.' else ""
    val pathParent = if (parent != null) parent + '.' else ""

    "views.html." + pathGrandParent + pathParent + page
  }

  def loadClass(name: String): Class[_] =  {
    try {
      Play.current.classloader.loadClass(name)
    } catch {
        case _: Throwable => {
          Play.current.classloader.loadClass(name + ".index")
        }
    }
  }

  def buildView(name: String): Html = {
    val clazz = loadClass(name)
    clazz.getDeclaredMethod("render").invoke(clazz).asInstanceOf[play.twirl.api.Html]
  }
}
```

I'd imagine that there is a much, much better way of doing the index view part then a try/catch, but it's fine for the tool I'm building